# How can I debug Openstack Dashboard?

Tags: python, django, debugging, openstack, openstack-horizon

I'm running the Openstack Cloud System. I installed and deployed the kilo version on the server successful, but this is only the default version of Openstack. So that, I want to have some modifies on this openstack source and add more features to it.

I started to change something with the Openstack Dashboard. However, there are some problems happened. Therefore, I have debugged this django web application. All everything I have configured is the same as the official tutorials on the openstack website (http://docs.openstack.org).

So, I have search on my server and find out 2 places that have the sources:

- The first one is /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/
- The second one is /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/
- And the config file is /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py

I set the option Debug = True in local_settings.py file.

On the server I typed these commands:

```
cd /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/
python manage.py runserver
```

Here is the output:

```
RemovedInDjango18Warning: XViewMiddleware has been moved to django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.
WARNING:py.warnings:RemovedInDjango18Warning: XViewMiddleware has been moved to django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.
RemovedInDjango18Warning: XViewMiddleware has been moved to django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.
WARNING:py.warnings:RemovedInDjango18Warning: XViewMiddleware has been moved to django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 05, 2015 - 09:28:50
Django version 1.7.6, using settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But in the browser, it shows the error:

[image: error]

And then, on the console, it shows:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[05/Aug/2015 10:21:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Not Found: /horizon/auth/login/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[05/Aug/2015 10:21:29] "GET /horizon/auth/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4237                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Not Found: /favicon.ico                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[05/Aug/2015 10:21:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4206
```

Please help me to get out of this problems. And how can to debug Openstack Django Website properly.Thank you very much !

Comment: You have to add the Auth urls to the url.py file - Iam not sure how Openstack implemented this - where at the documentation / tutorial are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you run server by runserver command you should go to the root url like
127.0.0.1:8000/
not
127.0.0.1:8000/horizon

The difference is in running method.
When you installed openstack_dashboard there is apache config that listen to address http://host/horizon look in to /etc/apache2/conf/sites-available/

The directories

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/

Is like the framework for all dashboards

> /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/

Is the default dashboard for openstack

> /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py

The config file for dashboard. Here you can apply changes for default dash, for example attach your project that modifies or extends default dash

So, your problem will be solved if you follow that link http://127.0.0.1:8000/
For debugging use

pdb or ide with integrated debugger

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I type 127.0.0.1:8000 on the browser and ENTER, it will redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/horizon/auth/login/?next=/ and show "Page Not Found"

Comment: Thank you, it's almost working now. There are some minor bugs about urls but it's not a big deal, it could be ignored when debugging. So, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link.
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/quickstart.html

Once this is done, add pdb statements to your code that you wish to debug.Go into the horizon folder and run the following command
./run_tests.sh --runserver 127.0.0.1:port_number

Instead of local host you can put in the IP address where horizon is running

Answer (score 0):

I have written the OpenStack documentation for debugging dashboards using PyCharm.
(It is good for any Openstack Dashboard including Horizon)
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/mistral/developer/troubleshooting.html